# How to scipy optimize minimize with trust-ncg

Tags: numpy, optimization, scipy, minimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have as an assignment to use the `'trust-ncg'` method of `scipy.opt.minimize`.
I have given the outputs of my function `f(x,y)`. I manually find the Jacobian in a function. So, also the Hessian. Simplified, it is:

```py
def foo(params):
  x,y = params
  return x*x+y

def df(params):  # jacobian
  x,y = params
  return np.array([2*x, 1])

def hf(params):  # hessian
  x,y = params
  return np.array([[2, 0], [0, 0])
```

Then, my attempt is:
res = opt.minimize(foo, [1, 1], jac=df, hess=hf, method='trust-ncg', tol=1e-10)

I receive: `ValueError: shapes (2,11) and (2,11) not aligned: 11 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)`.

I was playing with the tolerance, as in https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/57330/scipy.optimize.minimize. If I set the tolerance to 1, I would do only 1 iteration, but then I would simply return a straight line, which is not my goal.
I also tried to change the order of the arguments of the function, which had no effect as expected. I tried other versions of the hessian, as 1d array, but it did not help me. I also tried the jacobian to be of the type [[0], [1]]. Again, no effect.

How to properly call scipy opt minimize with trust-ncg?

Comment: I see that in "XX/XX/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_trustregion_ncg.py", line 90, in solve
    dBd = np.dot(d, Bd)

Comment: Which version of SciPy are you using (cf. e.g. `scipy.__version__`)? Your example code works fine here. Where do you get the 11 from?

Answer (score 0):

try transpose any of your matrices `arr.T` for allignment in inner `matrix multiplication` being done by scipy.optimize.minimize implementation, need shapes (2,11) and (11,2) TO BE aligned for multiplication, because matrices need to be *transposed* relative each other when are multiplied to each other - that will be correct:

1st Arr: (**dim 1**) 11 elements == 2nd Arr: (**dim 0**) 11 elements